# Stop pagination loop with Xpath

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, web-scraping

I am successfully using the xpath shown on the code below to select the web page following the one displayed on browser screen.

How to modify the xpath so that it stops the pagination loop when the page number is  equal to 50 or after 50 pages?

```
//a[@class='active_page']/following::a[1]

<div id="pagination">
   <ul class="zPagination">
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page/1">«</a></li>
      <li><a class="active_page" href="http://example.com/page/1">1</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page/2">2</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page/3">3</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page/XX">XX</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://example.com/page/60">»</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use below XPath to match links for only first 50 pages:

```
//a[@class='active_page']/following::a[position()=1 and number(text())<51]
```

For pages after 50:

```
//a[@class='active_page']/following::a[position()=1 and number(text())>50]
```

Comment: What an epic approach!!! You always come up with something new. However, could you please tell me why you used `number(text())`? Sorry for my ignorance. Plus one for this.

Comment: Because `text()` returns string (e.g. `"50"`) which you cannot compare with the integer (e.g. `50`) due to different types. So `number()` allows to convert `text()` value into integer

Comment: @Andersson Thank You. The suggested code is working, even though, but this is a problem of the program used, the loop process restart again from page 1 after page 50 is reached.

Comment: @Mkgl , Can you update your question with the code you use? Or you might also create new question and add your code with my XPath suggestion applied

Comment: @Andersson no problem, for me the question is answered. The code I have tested is the first line of code of your suggestion (first 50 pages). Thank you.